# How to remove the first occurance of a sub string in a string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a HTML content in the form of `String`. There are many hyper links in the string. How can I remove only first link in the string? Please guide me.

```
String html = "abcdef<a href=some dynamic url>link1</a>ghijkl<a href=some url>link2</a>mnopq<a href=some url>link3</a>";
```

I want to remove the "link1" along with reference url from above string.

Comment: Use [HTML parser](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If the problem is the 'first occurrence' part - [replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). But do show us an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/892914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
String matchATag="<a[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>";
html=html.replaceFirst(matchATag,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression.
Example:

```
html.replaceFirst("<a[^>]+>[^>]+</a>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to match the link element with regex, but that's a [recipe for problems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You'd better get an HTML parser like [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), find the first link, and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For html processing i would suggest jsoup (http://jsoup.org/). You can also specify the replacement behaviour in this lib.